# Is it ok to overload implementation of an interface?

Tags: java

I've recently had to break a simple class down into two versions, a Legacy version for older client versions, and a newer version that has migrated to a separate interface.

As there is much common code, I split this down into an abstract class with 2 concrete classes. With a structure as in the below:

```
interface ParentInt {
    // Common methods
}

interface ChildIntA extends ParentInt {
    // Legacy methods
}

interface ChildIntB extends ParentInt {
    // New model methods
}

abstract class AbstParentClass implements ParentInt {
    // ...
}

class LegacyConcreteClass extends AbstParentClass implements ChildIntA {
    // ...
}

class NewConcreteClass extends AbstParentClass implements ChildIntB {
    // ...
}
```

What I'm wondering is whether there are any pitfalls I might encounter because AbstParentClass implements ParentInt and the two concrete classes also implement children of this interface? Might there be a better pattern for this situation?

My code currently all works regardless of whether AbstParentClass has this implements directive or not. In fact, because the two concrete classes are instantiated separately in different threads, AbstParentClass is never actually referenced directly anywhere else.

In my situation the interfaces are part of an API and as such are unchangeable from my POV.

Comment: You should be able to inherit from as many interfaces as you want even when they extend each other. You can't however inherit from more then one class (but you're not doing that so you should be fine :))

Comment: Everyone is commenting about the missing "extends AbstParentClass" in the child declarations; I am sure that was just an oversight as this is clearly not real code. I've added those declarations in so we can discuss the real situation.

Comment: Thanks, Ernest, you're right, it was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problems with this approach. I understand your concern about the apparent "multiple inheritance", but the way that Java handles interfaces ensures that this kind of thing is never actually an issue. Interface methods with the same signature are "fused" and only one implementation method is allowed or required, regardless of how many identical interface methods are inherited.

Answer (score 2):

There's no *technical* problems. Whether it makes sense in your application is a separate issue, but we don't know enough to answer that.

The other thing that may or may not be an issue is the new interface being tied specifically to the legacy interface. If the legacy interface goes away, you'd need to either un-tie the two, or keep the cruft.

It might be easier to keep them separated by having the new class(es) implement two interfaces. Whether or not it makes sense to extend an abstract base class becomes a bit murkier then.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. The interfaces themselves are from an internal API that I've not changed. The "legacy" interface is not going to go away, although the legacy concrete class may be deprecated in future. I've updated my example to reflect this.

Comment: @TomElliott Then no, I don't see any issues at all--this isn't an uncommon pattern, although if nothing is ever referred to as-a `ParentInt` I might think about it.